# How to use __getitem__ to return objects in an object tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a named tuple that I loaded from a json

```
with open(self._json_path) as data_file:
    self._dom = json.load(data_file, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

I access content of this object tree by referring

```
self._dom.my_var.A
```

If, however, optional attributes in the JSON are not set, I run into an exception trying to access them.

So

```
  self._dom.my_var.B
```

would not work in case B is not defined in the JSON file.

For that I would like offer a save way to access nullable objects with `__getitem__`. If they are not defined, I return None.

This piece of code does not work as it seems that self.dom.key looks up an attribute literally named "key" and will not run in an attribute error even there is a object within the object tree defined.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        return self.dom.key
    except AttributeError:
        return None
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: `self.dom.key` looks up an attribute literally named "key".  You want `getattr(self.dom, key, None)`, I think.

Comment: will try that out, thx

Comment: Note, this: `object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())` is incredibly wasteful. It creates a *new* `namedtuple` *class* for *every* single object in your JSON, even if they have the same exact keys, obliviating the nice, memory compactness of `namedtuple` objects. Instead, use a similar approach to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/a6efe3de57548b17429fffb8a5d08b2e) using a cache. Note, I was giving an example of how to convert `pandas.Series` objects, but it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code solved it.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    obj = self.dom
    try:
        for k in key.split("."):
            obj = getattr(obj, k)
    except AttributeError:
        return None
    return obj
```

edit
and there is a shorter version

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    f = attrgetter(key)
    return f(self.dom)
```